# How to access database from other app in Django in same project

Tags: django

I am new to Django, the way I understand the database migration structure is allotted per app. If I have several apps inside the project, how do I refer the models/data in database on another apps?

Let's say I have these apps:

- Home
- Expense
- Income

I have created User, Balance, Expense, Income models on Home app. How do I access these data on Expense and Income?

Is there a better way to implement project structure as I am not quite sure that my current implementation is the right one. Is it correct to implement models that should be accessible from all apps within a certain app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to add all your apps into INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

And then you can import other apps' models by

```
from expense.models import MODEL_NAME
```